# Is it possible to use nmcli completely without nm-applet?

Tags: networking, command-line, network-manager, window-manager, connection

Since I don't use GNOME now and try wmii, the nm-applet is no longer available for me.I know there is nmcli for the control. What I'm really interested in is that can it really be a substitute for nm-applet.

`man nmcli`, there are these words, which makes me confused:

1. It is not meant as a replacement of nm-applet or other similar clients.

   **What does *other similar clients* mean?**
2. The use case comprise:

   - Servers, headless machines:*No GUI* is available; then nmcli is used to talk *directly* to NetworkManager and control only system-wide connections.
   - User sessions: For this case, `nmcli` can talk to `nm-applet` to find user connections.It can still talk *directly* to NetworkManager for manipulating these connections.  As `nmcli` *doesn't* have direct access to user configuration data in GConf, `nm-applet` handles that itself.  That may, for example, cause the applet to pop up keyring dialogs when secrets are needed.

   **As `nmcli` can work directly without X, Why can't it work as well when secrets are needed?**

PS. Is there any alternate easy approach to control connections using command line?

Answer (score 3):

First of all let me say that `nm-applet` can be used in environments other than Gnome: I used it successfully in [`awesome`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) and in [`openbox`](http://openbox.org/).

`nmcli` do not provide the same functionalities of `nm-applet`, e.g. you cannot configure new connections.

A valid alternative to connect to wired or wireless networks from command line is [`wicd-curses`](https://launchpad.net/wicd).

Answer (score 1):

similar clients mean applications that do similar things as nm-applet, but isn't nm-applet. Since Network Manager is driven by DBus, anyone is free to write clients to control it without interacting with Network Managers code in any way. It's sort of like how you can connect to a web server with different browsers without changing the server.

Headless servers doesn't need secrets the same way a laptop does.

I don't think the manpage says you can't use secrets. It says that if you have nm-applet installed, then it can be reused to provide per-user network configurations and personal passwords. If it isn't available, then I assume you would have to provide the secrets yourself.

I don't normally use Network Manager from the command line. But it uses DBus, so it would be relatively easy to write a curses-application for it, or something. Or you could just use dbus-end manually, but that might not be pleasant.

Comment: I think I should read the manual more carefully. BTW,are there any friendly but powerful tools as substitutes for networkmanager from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line to configure a connection. For example, this command will create a vpn connection:

```
nmcli con add type vpn ifname '*' vpn-type libreswan
```

If you need a secret then you can edit the config files for a vpn directly.  These are located at

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/[connection name].
```

Open the file in your favorite editor and add the lines

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=[my password]
```

---

If you give a man a command he can use linux for the day, if you teach a man to man, he will be a professional

Comment: On which version of Ubuntu should this work? Ubuntu 14.04.3 has `nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8` which does not understand `nmcli con add …`: `Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }` `COMMAND := { list | status | up | down | delete }`.

Comment: OK, it seems that since Ubuntu 15.04 there is [nmcli 0.9.10.0](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/nmcli.1.html) which supports `nmcli con add …`. ...but this version of Ubuntu was not available at the time of writing your answer :)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can use nmcli to connect instead of nm-applet. you can totally control your network connection using command line.

Comment: Can you develop your answer? For instance, can you answer the two bold questions of Hongxu Chen? Thank you